# Where is payment(py_) API doc in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I found that there is a type of id start with `py_`,
It is unique id for payments,
but I have never seen it in Stripe API doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`py_` objects have the same API shape as the [Charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object). They are fundamentally the same thing, but in most cases represent a transaction/transfer between two Stripe accounts (i.e. with Connect) or non-card payment methods.

See [Creating destination charges on your platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) for more details.

Comment: do you happen to know if there is any official Stripe documentation that says so? I haven't found it anywhere.